# Let pandoc number sections without h1

Tags: markdown, pandoc

When I am writing a documentation with markdown (in order to process it to HTML with pandoc), I always have one heading of first order (`# Heading`), which is the document title, and multiple headings of second order (`## Heading`).

But when I switch on `--number-sections` in pandoc, all headings have a leading number for the document title.

How can I prevent that? Is there a parameter that `h1`-like headings should not be numbered, or should I specify the title in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual [states](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) that

> Headers with the class unnumbered will not be numbered, even if --number-sections is specified.

For that, you just need to append `{-}` at the end of the header line

Edit: it might also be better if you specify the title within the YAML metadata (at least that's how I do it with jekyll and similar tools)

Comment: Using the `{-}` makes all lower-range headings carry a `0.` in front of their number. I did it with the YAML title now and pulled all headings one level up.

Comment: I compile markdown to pdf via latex and with this `{-}` at the end of the first header, I also get all the other header-numbers starting with 0 now. Is there a way to fix this automtically, e.g., with a flag when compling, without any detours over intermediate output, or so? I just want one quick command...

Answer (score 1):

`--shift-heading-level-by=-1` works for me.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.