# Specify Pandoc HTML numbering to start from <h2>

Tags: html, markdown, h2, pandoc

I want to convert a markdown to HTML with header numbering, starting from `<h2>`.
What's the way to achieve it?

`pandoc` provides the option `--number-sections` (or `-N`) so headers are numbered in the output.
Now I am trying to convert markdown to HTML with this option.

In default, the output HTML header level of `pandoc` starts from `<h1>`. It is not ideal and so I want to change it to `<h2>` (whereas the original markdown may contain many first-level headers, the output HTML should contain at most 1 `<h1>`).

It is possible to specify `--shift-heading-level-by=1`; then, the output header level starts from `<h2>` (see [Official Pandoc User's Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) and maybe also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496417/let-pandoc-number-sections-without-h1)).
However, it would mess up the section-numbering! Basically, the level of the section numbering shifts, too. Now all sections are under "0" (like 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, …) and no sections of 1 exist.

`pandoc` provides another option `--number-offset=1` but what it does is just offseting the numbers like "0.1"→"1.1". Then, all section numbers start from 1 with no sections numbered 2. Obviously, it makes no sense. The initial prefix number "1." is redundant and should be removed from all the section numbers like 1.1→1, 1.1.4→1.4, 1.2.3→2.3, etc.

For demonstration purposes, here is a sample markdown text file (`abc.md`)

```markdown
%Test-md

# First Header (1) #

## Header (1-1) ##

# Second Header (2) #

## Header (2-2) ##

### Header (2-3) ###
```

and its output HTML (simplified) with

```bash
pandoc -N --section-divs --shift-heading-level-by=1 -t html5 abc.md
```

```html
<section id="first-header-1" data-number="0.1">
  <h2 data-number="0.1">0.1 First Header (1)</h2>
    <section id="header-1-1" data-number="0.1.1">
      <h3 data-number="0.1.1">0.1.1 Header (1-1)</h3>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section id="second-header-2" data-number="0.2">
    <h2 data-number="0.2">0.2 Second Header (2)</h2>
      <section id="header-2-2" data-number="0.2.1">
        <h3 data-number="0.2.1">0.2.1 Header (2-2)</h3>
        <section id="header-2-3" data-number="0.2.1.1">
          <h4 data-number="0.2.1.1">0.2.1.1 Header (2-3)</h4>
       </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

How can one make pandoc do the numbering in the ordinary way (1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2.1) yet output the HTML with the header level starting from `<h2>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandoc first shifts the headings, then does the numbering. This is not what we want here though, we'd like the numbering to happen first. A pandoc [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) can be used to take control of this.

The function `pandoc.utils.make_sections` performs the action that's triggered by passing `--section-divs` or `--number-sections` on the command line. Matching the effect of `--shift-heading-level-by=1` is possible by modifying all `Header` elements manually:

```lua
function Pandoc (doc)
  -- Create and number sections. Setting the first parameter to
  -- `true` ensures that headings are numbered.
  doc.blocks = pandoc.utils.make_sections(true, nil, doc.blocks)

  -- Shift the heading levels by 1
  doc.blocks = doc.blocks:walk {
    Header = function (h)
      h.level = h.level + 1
      return h
    end
  }

  -- Return the modified document
  return doc
end
```

The filter would be used by saving it to a file `shifted-numbered-headings.lua`. It can then be passed to pandoc via the `--lua-filter`/`-L` parameter. The `--number-sections`/`-N` option must still be passed for the numbering to become visible, and `--section-divs` is still required to get `<section>` elements.

```bash
pandoc \
    --lua-filter=shifted-numbered-headings.lua \
    --number-sections \
    --section-divs \
    ...
```

The `class` that pandoc sets on the `<section>` elements will always reflect the actual tagging level: the `<section>` that wraps an `<h2>` heading will have `class="level2"`, even if, conceptually, it is a first level heading. This may be confusing and, unfortunately, cannot be changed with a filter.

Comment: Confirmed this works! It seems only the practical difference in the output from my own answer is the numbering of the `class` attributes (they are **not** wrong but different).

Comment: @MasaSakano thank you! I hadn't notice the different `class` values and have amended my answer to make that possible shortcoming a bit more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

So far, the easiest solution I have found is to make it in two steps. First, convert a markdown to HTML with no shift in the header levels. Then, *convert the HTML* to another HTML in which the header level is shifted by 1: `<h1>` → `<h2>`.

Here is an example code:

```bash
pandoc -N --section-divs -t html5 /tmp/try1.md |\
  pandoc --from=html -t html5 --shift-heading-level-by=1 > output.html
```

Notice `--from=html` in the second `pandoc` -- it is necessary because otherwise pandoc would not know the file type of the streaming (pipe) input.

Here is the (simplified) output.  There is now no redundant common prefix like "0." or "1." in the section-header numbers.

```html
<section id="first-header-1" data-number="1">
  <h2 data-number="1">1 First Header (1)</h2>
    <section id="header-1-1" data-number="1.1">
      <h3 data-number="1.1">1.1 Header (1-1)</h3>
    </section>
</section>
<section id="second-header-2" data-number="2">
  <h2 data-number="2">2 Second Header (2)</h2>
    <section id="header-2-2" data-number="2.1">
      <h3 data-number="2.1">2.1 Header (2-2)</h3>
        <section id="header-2-3" data-number="2.1.1">
          <h4 data-number="2.1.1">2.1.1 Header (2-3)</h4>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

As a note, `number-offset` is irrelevant because it is to specify the numbering to start from a different number from the default 1 or 0 and does nothing with the section-numbering *level*.